# Unknown grey areas

Tags: mapbox, legend

There is no legend and I cannot find any help to tell me what the gray patches represent on geojson.io maps:

[image]

e.g. http://bl.ocks.org/d/77e214b9936fd7f1d29d9641f0248988

This is especially curious as I find mobile compass sensor data going really bad within some of these shadowy representations, off by as much as 90 degrees, although that may be a coincidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that is the hill shading. You can open up the Mapbox Streets style in Mapbox Studio Classic, https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio-classic/ to confirm.